# Multiple UPDATEs in one Access SQL query

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I'm trying to make a query like so:

```
UPDATE table1 SET col1 = 'foo', col2 = 'bar';
UPDATE table2 SET hi = 'bye', bye = 'hi';
```

But when I go to save, Access errors with:

> Characters found after end of SQL statement

After some searching, it would appear this is because Access can only do one query at a time.

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you make a VB procedure executing the two statements?

Comment: Yes, you can only create/execute one query at a time when using "Create > Query".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Where are you working? You can run multiple queries in VBA or via macros. Some examples:

```
CurrentDB.Execute "UPDATE table1 SET col1 = 'foo', col2 = 'bar';", dbFailOnError
CurrentDB.Execute "UPDATE table2 SET hi = 'bye', bye = 'hi';", dbFailOnError
```

Saved query:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "Query5", dbFailOnError
```

Answer (score -1):

I found this sample:

[MS ACCESS 2007: UPDATE QUERY THAT UPDATES VALUES IN ONE TABLE WITH VALUES FROM ANOTHER TABLE](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/queries/update2_2007.php)

uses the designer to create the query easily:

```
UPDATE Big INNER JOIN Bot ON Big.PART = Bot.PART
SET Bot.MFG = [Big].[MFG];
```